# How to scrape id attribute from HTML with bs4?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a specific piece of data from HTML.

```
html = '''<p transform="translate(3,15)" class="SoccerPlayer SoccerPlayer-1 Soccer-Team  Outcome-Positive" id="12-8-3">
<p transform="translate(89,20)" class="SoccerPlayer SoccerPlayer-514 Soccer-Team Outcome-Positive" data-id="12-9-229">'''
```

From this piece of html I'm attempting to scrape the `class`, and `id` attributes.

I've tried

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
for pr in soup.find_all("p"):
    print(pr['class'], pr['id'])
```

but I get a keyerror on `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue here is that the second element do not have an attribute `id`, there is only a `data-id`, so you have to check that or use [`.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=get#dict.get) if you’re not sure an attribute is defined:

```
pr.get('id')
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

html = '''<p transform="translate(3,15)" class="SoccerPlayer SoccerPlayer-1 Soccer-Team  Outcome-Positive" id="12-8-3">
<p transform="translate(89,20)" class="SoccerPlayer SoccerPlayer-514 Soccer-Team Outcome-Positive" data-id="12-9-229">'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for pr in soup.find_all("p"):
    print(pr["class"], pr.get('id'))
```

##### Output

```
['SoccerPlayer', 'SoccerPlayer-1', 'Soccer-Team', 'Outcome-Positive'] 12-8-3
['SoccerPlayer', 'SoccerPlayer-514', 'Soccer-Team', 'Outcome-Positive'] None
```

---

An ugly alternative is to iterate the attributes and search for any attribute contains `id`:

```
print(pr["class"], pr.get([a for a in pr.attrs if 'id' in a][0]))

->
['SoccerPlayer', 'SoccerPlayer-1', 'Soccer-Team', 'Outcome-Positive'] 12-8-3
['SoccerPlayer', 'SoccerPlayer-514', 'Soccer-Team', 'Outcome-Positive'] 12-9-229
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is trying to use the `find_all()` method without first initializing an instance of `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

html_data = '''<p transform="translate(3,15)" class="SoccerPlayer SoccerPlayer-1 Soccer-Team  Outcome-Positive" id="12-8-3"'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, 'html.parser')

for pr in soup.find_all("p"):
    print(pr["class"], pr["id"])
```